# Any approach toward speech to text in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have to implemented a speech to text mechanism but cant find any possible way, I have looked up but it only recognizes particular words, my requirements are more of siri like where every word spoken by user is converted into text.

want one perfect demo if anyone have prepared so share it please with me

Thanks :-)

Comment: https://github.com/mzeeshanid/iOS-Speech-To-Text

Comment: please help me if anyone have idea abt this

Comment: @rushabh thanks for reply but its working on google API and that is old so please if you have any other solution then please help me

Comment: Please help me if anyone have prepared this kind of demo so provide me link

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented speech to text with a [Nuance solution](https://developer.nuance.com/public/index.php?task=home) in the past.  It is not free however, but nothing Siri-like will be.

Answer (score 0):

You can you nuance dragon API. Developer version will be available with limited number of speech to text conversions.

CMU Sphinx/PocketSphinx is an another option. It is an another powerful open source toolkit for speech synthesis. Here it allows you to  to build and customize   acoustic models.